# Observe Checkboxes in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form which consists of a header section then a FormArray which contains repeated sets of controls. I then add a new instance of the FormGroup to the array each time a user presses the add item button. I create the repeated section with this code:

```
trainingSetItems = new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
          'select': new FormControl(null),
          'reps': new FormControl(null),
          'distance': new FormControl(null),
          'discipline': new FormControl(null),
          'rest': new FormControl(null),
          'interval': new FormControl(null)
        })
      ]);
```

I'm wanting to monitor all the 'select' controls and update an array that contains a list of the selected FormArray indexes. I also want activate some other controls when items are selected.

How do I attach an observable to the select form control to do this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You can watch changes in your form doing the following: `<yourFormVariable>.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => ...).`

Comment: I did try that, but I was trying to only subscribe to the select form controls. Do you have to do it for the whole form?

Comment: What select you mean? This `select: new FormControl(null),`?

Comment: Yeah I was going    select: new FormControl(null).valueChanges.subscribe... but this wouldn't compile. There were errors around type Subscription not assignable to type AbstractControl.

Comment: You can't do this inside the `Form` declaration. Also, In your case, you are using `FormArray`, so I think you want to get the changes of the whole array, right? In `ngOnInit` do this: `trainingSetItems.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => ...)`

Comment: Ok. That makes a bit more sense. Thanks for that.